# Solr 7 Query Synonyms with Multiple Terms with Whitespace

Tags: solr, whitespace, synonym, search-multiple-words

I know this question was asked for a few times, but I did not get it until now...

So, I want to search for "ms sql", but not only "ms" or "sql". When I use quotationmarks the score is much higher than without.

I tried to use ShingleFilterFactory to get the combined results. But it doesn't work. In my query the synonymys are not be used, just the word I typed in. And the results are always 0.

I also saw some solutions with exact mapping like:

```
MS SQL, Microsoft SQL, MSSQL => MSSQL
```

to delete the whitespace. But I need the exact matched words at the end, so I can't do this at index time.

My schema.xml looks like:

```
[...]
<field name="Beschreibung" type="text" stored="true" indexed="true"/>
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
[...]
<analyzer type="index">
  <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="0" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0" preserveOriginal="1" types="types.txt"/>
  <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>

<analyzer type="query" >
  <tokenizer  class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" maxShingleSize="3" outputUnigrams="false"/>
  <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt" tokenizerFactory="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
  <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="0" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0" preserveOriginal="1" types="types.txt"/>
  <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
```

My synonyms.txt:

```
MSSQL, MS SQL, Microsoft SQL
```

When I changed something in my schema.xml I always restart Solr.

If you need more details please let me know.

I hope you can help me.

Comment: So essentially whenever you search "ms sql", you want to get documents which has "ms sql" or "MSSQL", or "MS SQL" or "Microsoft SQL" but not anything which has just "ms" or "sql". is that correct ?

Comment: yes,that is correct.